# Data from model not inserted in QTableView

Tags: qt4, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

I am trying to insert some data in a `TableView` from a model but I am doing something wrong because the data is not inserted. The table is updated with the columns and rows though.

So I have a `GraphicsView` where I am drawing some custom `GraphicsItems`. Each time a new Item is added to the scene the model is supposed to get updated and send a signal to my `TableView` to insert the data in it as well.

Here I update the model when the new item is added:

```
    Clothoid *temp = new Clothoid();
        temp->setStartPoint(p1);
        temp->setEndPoint(p2);

        clothoids.append(temp);

        scene->addItem(temp);

        model.setColumnCount(3);
        model.setRowCount(clothoids.size());

        QModelIndex index = model.index(clothoids.size(), 1, QModelIndex());
        model.setData(index, clothoids.last()->startCurvature);
        index = model.index(clothoids.size(), 2, QModelIndex());
        model.setData(index, clothoids.last()->endCurvature);
        index = model.index(clothoids.size(), 3, QModelIndex());
        model.setData(index, clothoids.last()->clothoidLength);

        emit clothoidAdded(&model);
```

Clothoids being a list of my custom graphicsItems:

```
QList < Clothoid *> clothoids;
```

The signal is connected to the slot in my main window:

```
   

    ui->setupUi(this);    
        SpinBoxDelegate delegate;
        ui->clothoidTable->setItemDelegate(&delegate);

        connect(ui->graphicsView, SIGNAL(clothoidAdded(QStandardItemModel*)), ui->clothoidTable, SLOT(onClothoidAdded(QStandardItemModel*)));
```

where the slot is:

```
    void TableViewList::onClothoidAdded(QStandardItemModel *model)
        {
            setModel(model);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to be calling setData() directly. Here's a few key steps you need to take:

- **Your model should hold a container (QList, perhaps) of `Clothoid` pointers** (whether it is responsible for freeing the resources or not). The index into the container should map directly to what row it occupies in the view.
- **Your `data()` and `setData()` need to be implemented correctly**, such that the model knows what Clothoid info goes in each cell for a given row. They should have `switch()` statements on an `enum` *representing column number*, like this:

---

```
// in data() after the usual error checking, etc
if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
    Clothoid* cloth = myListOfClothoids.at(index.row());
    switch(index.column())
        {
        // This enum is defined in the header for the Clothoid class 
        //  and represents the COLUMN NUMBER in which to show the data
        case Clothoid::START: 
            return cloth->startCurvature; // these probably shouldn't be public members btw
        case Clothoid::END:
            return cloth->endCurvature;
        case Clothoid::LENGTH:
            return cloth->clothoidLength;
        }
    }
```

---

```
// in setData()
if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
    Clothoid* cloth = myListOfClothoids.at(index.row());
    switch(index.column())
        {
        case Clothoid::START: 
            cloth->startCurvature = variant.toWhatever(); 
            break;
        case Clothoid::END:
            cloth->endCurvature = variant.toWhateverElse(); 
            break;
        case Clothoid::LENGTH:
            cloth->clothoidLength = variant.toYetSomethingElse();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    emit dataChanged(index,index);
    return true;
    }
```

1. **Your model should have an `addClothoid()` function.** In this function you want to do something like:

---

```
int rowIndexFirst = 0; // insert into first row
int rowIndexLast = rowIndexFirst; // only inserting one row/Clothoid
beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowIndexFirst, rowIndexLast);
myListOfClothoids.prepend(newClothoidPtr); // insert clothoid into first index, as well
endInsertRows(); // begin and end take care of signalling the view for you!
```

I really suggest doing this. Yes, its a lot of work to refactor to this extent, but its worth it, trust me.

Hope this helps.